# How do I Mock SpringApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(SpecificBeanName.class) call

Tags: java, unit-testing

I Have a Test java class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and I need to create a test method for a method that using the following row:

```
SpringApplicationContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(SpecificBeanName.class);
```

The test method failed with `NullPointerException`, I guess it's because the context is `null`.

How can I use Mockito to Mock this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be mocking `applicationContext`. You should just create a 
separate config file such as `myAppTest.xml` with your test beans.

Source:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/43769-mocking-applicationcontext-for-unit-tests